# Upload audio bytes data in memory to AWS S3 bucket as a .wav file in python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, audio, wav

I have bytes data of the audio file. I want to store it in S3 Bucket as a .wav file. Currently I'm storing it into a temporary folder and then copying it into S3. This will increase the time because of I/O operations to disk locally.

I wanted to know if there is any way in which we can directly store this bytes data into S3 as wav file. I am able to extract the nChannels, sampWidth, other parameters from the bytes data that are required to construct the wav file

I couldn't find much answers for this